# Get argument of executed function in function Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that measures time execution of function, and cleans DOM after each execution:

```
function measureTimeExecution(domID, testFunc){
    console.time("timer");
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       testFunc();
       var getDiv = document.getElementById(domID);
    }
    getDiv.empty();
    console.timeEnd("timer");
}
```

Function that creates new ul

```
 function createList_Task_2(divID){
        var createNewUL = document.createElement("ul");
        createNewUL.id = "phoneList";
        document.getElementById(divID).appendChild(createNewUL);
        for(var i = 0; i < phones.length;i++){

            var chunk = "<li>" + phones[i].age +"<br>" + phones[i].id +"<br><img src='"
                + phones[i].imageUrl  +"'/><br>"  + phones[i].name + "<br>" + phones[i].snippet + "</li>";

            document.getElementById("phoneList").innerHTML += chunk;
        }
    }
```

But iy gives me: Uncaught TypeError: testFunc is not a function;

Example:

```
measureTimeExecution("div1", createList_Task_3("div1"));
```

Is it possible to get somehow domID in measureTimeExecution as a argument of testFunc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that when you are calling `measureTimeExecution` you are runing the parameter, instead pass a function again.

look at this code it should work

```
measureTimeExecution("div1", function () { createList_Task_3("div1"); });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function measureTimeExecution(domID, testFunc)
```

The function expects the second argument to be a function, but calling it like `measureTimeExecution("div1", createList_Task_3("div1"));`, it provides the return of `createList_Task_3("div1")`. Since `createList_Task_3` returns nothing, the default return is `undefined`.

For it to be a function as well as be able to be provided the ID, it should return a function like this:

```
function createList_Task_2(divID){
  return function(){
    var createNewUL = document.createElement("ul");
    createNewUL.id = "phoneList";
    document.getElementById(divID).appendChild(createNewUL);
    for(var i = 0; i < phones.length;i++){

        var chunk = "<li>" + phones[i].age +"<br>" + phones[i].id +"<br><img src='"
            + phones[i].imageUrl  +"'/><br>"  + phones[i].name + "<br>" + phones[i].snippet + "</li>";

        document.getElementById("phoneList").innerHTML += chunk;
    }
  }
}
```